# What is meant by ESX host/ hardware

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, vmware

I am very much new to this word ESX. We recently decided to upgrade our existing hardware to upgrade with ESX host/hardware to boost the application performance.

What is this ESX host/hardware... and How does it improve the performance...

Thanks in advance. Regards,
UDAY

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ESX was a product from VMWare.

It's basically a "server" for Virtual Machines.

It's current name is "VSphere".

You can read about it, and closely related technologies and products, here:

- http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere/esxi-and-esx/index.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_ESX
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor

Answer (score 4):

> What is this ESX host/hardware...
>   ESX is an operating system acts as a hypervisor that hosts other virtual machines. it's not hardware.
>
> and How does it improve the performance...
>   Since you can run multiple instances of virtual machines simultaneously, this basically lets you utilize your hardware much better. at the end it depends on your usage of the machine. Virtualization is good - but not for all use cases.

Answer (score 0):

ESX means Elastic Sky. Sky referring to the cloud which you can expand and contract resources as you need.

https://communities.vmware.com/people/raffic_ncc/blog/2013/07/01/difference-between-vmware-esx-and-esxi